# Как поменять маску для инпута?

Tags: javascript, jquery

использую jquery.inputmask/

сейчас у меня
99/9999

пробую поменять на aa|9999

(тоесть 2 буквы можно ввести, потом 4 цифры)

но так не будет работать

```js
$('.input').inputmask('99/99999999', {
  "oncomplete": function() {
    $(this).addClass('completed');
  },
  "onincomplete": function() {
    $(this).removeClass('completed');
  },
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.8-beta.7/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понял что у вас не получается. Вот все работает.

```js
$('#input1').inputmask('aa/99999999');
$('#input2').inputmask('aa|99999999');
$('#input3').inputmask('aa\\|99999999');
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
<input type="text" id="input3">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.8-beta.7/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
```